# 20 identical balls to be distributed in 3 identical boxes with MAX & MIN balls in each box?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, permutations

As the title suggests, In how many ways can 20 identical balls be distributed in 3 identical boxes with at most 8 balls in each box and minimum 1 ball in each box ?

Comment: Number of distributions with minimum $1$ ball-Number of distributions with at least  $9$ balls in 1 at least 1 box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's not much leeway, so it's probably most efficient to count by hand: $8+8+4=20$, $8+7+5=20$, $8+6+6=20$, $7+7+6=20$ – that's it, $4$ ways.